# How to replace two PCRE search-replace with one?

Tags: pcre

I have two commands to change non-escaped spaces to tabs and then escaped spaces to regular spaces:

`perl -pe 's/(?<!\\) /\t/g' dupes.log|perl -pe 's/\\ / /g'|sponge dupes.log`

I always would like to learn more about regular expressions and so I'd like to write:

`perl -i -pe 's/I have no/idea what/g' dupes.log`

Care to tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)( )|\\ /$1 ? "\t" : " "/ge' dupes.log
```

Here,

- `(?<!\\)( )|\\`   - matches either a space not preceded with a `\` capturing the space into Group 1 or an escaped space char
- `$1 ? "\t" : " "` - if Group 1 was matched, replacement is a tab char, else, it is a simple regular space.

Mind the `e` flag that makes the regex engine treat the RHS as a Perl expression.

Comment: Hrmmm OK I was hoping for some regex wizardry here.

Comment: @chx Conditional replacement patterns are not that common, Boost, for example, supports them, and you can use them in Notepad++. Not with `perl` though.